# Why does printing a list output last item in list?

Tags: list, perl, printing

```
print "Val: " . ('a','b','c');
```

The output is:

> c

Why?

It doesn't matter how you do it.  It could be:

```
sub test {
    return ('a','b','c');
}
print "Val: " . test();
```

Comment: this does not happen with the code you show.  please show the actual code you are using that has a problem.

Comment: @ysth See edit to question

Comment: Welcome to the unique wonderful world of perl. The right of `.` expects a scalar value, and so the rhs - a list - evaluates to the last element, 'c'.

Comment: You can also use [`Baby cart operator`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod) like `print "Val:  @{[test()]}"` to interpolate list inside a string;

Comment: @JoopEggen: *"Welcome to the unique wonderful world of perl"* No tribalism please. The comma operator in C and C++ behaves the same way, and other languages probably follow suit. What would you expect `print "Val: " . ('a','b','c')` to do? It doesn't seem at all obvious to me what is wanted. All three expressions are evaluated in order, in case they have side-effects, and the value of the last evaluated one is used. I can't think of a better implementation, can you?

Comment: @Borodin let us not forget `@a = ('a','b','c');`. But you are right. my comment was born from the reminiscence from very early perl days, searching for what to write, what went wrong. _A more verbose (`-verbose`?) compiler could have warned_ `"'a' : no side-effect. expression discarded."`. That said I like it, that the comma is an operator too.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Perl takes the position that programmers generally know what they are doing, so checks on their behaviour aren't necessary except for the more obvious bugs. I don't believe that the obsession with preventing a programmer from writing nonsense that prevails in languages like C and Java is any help at all. Perl warns about mistakes like using an undefined variable, defining a hash with a missing value, or failing to escape a character within a string, and I much prefer being able to get a running program from my code to being slapped for every mistake I make.

Comment: @JoopEggen: I can't find it now, but I have read that Java is *"hard to get right, and hard to get wrong"* or something similar. The same applies to C++ and, in a different way, to C. Meanwhile there is a quote from Larry Wall *"Easy things should be easy, and hard things should be possible"*. I think that about sums it up.

Comment: @JoopEggen re "more verbose", if you enable warnings (which you should always do), it will say `Useless use of a constant ("a") in void context`, `Useless use of a constant ("b") in void context`

Answer (score 5):

http://blogs.perl.org/users/steven_haryanto/2012/09/the-comma-operator.html

explains the comma operator.  To quote them,

"...It is just the binary comma operator in action. In the scalar context, the comma operator (quoting the perlop manpage verbatim) "evaluates its left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right argument and returns that value. This is just like C's comma operator." So the end result is the rightmost argument..."

Answer (score 3):

The concatenation operator (`.`) takes two scalars as operands, so your list gets evaluated in scalar context.  As explained in roderick young's answer, a list returns its final value when evaluated in scalar context, due to the way the comma operator works.

If you want to print all of the items in the list, you can either use `,` instead of `.` in the `print` statement or (probably better) use `join` to convert the list to a scalar before concatenating:

```
$ perl -E 'say "Val: ", ("a", "b", "c")'
Val: abc
~$ perl -E 'say "Val: " . join("-", ("a", "b", "c"))'
Val: a-b-c
```